# Nginx Allow http for single resource when default is redirect to https

Tags: nginx

I configured my Nginx to redirect to all http requests to https

```
server {
    server_name url.net;
    listen 80 ;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
    server_name url.net;
    listen 443 ssl http2 ;
    ....
}
```

There is one specific resource at `url.net/file.xml` where I want to allow plain HTTP get requests without any redirect.

How can I configure that in nginx?

Answer (score 0):

Place the `return` statement into a `location` block, then add an exact match `location` block for the URI exception. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

For example:

```
server {
    server_name url.net;
    listen 80 ;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    location = /file.xml {
        root /path/to/directory;
    }
}
```

Note that this will **not** work if you have [HTTP Strict Transport Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) headers on your secure site.